# HTML drilldown table: Design

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to figure out the best way to construct a HTML drilldown table in terms of tags. It needs to be simple but most important it should be logical.

Is there any preferred standard on how to do this? What would you recommend?

One possible solution would be '**colspan**'.

```
<tbody>
<tr><td> + </td><td>Summery row 1</td><td>Summery row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td> + </td><td>Summery row 2</td><td>Summery row 2</td></tr>
<tr style=hidden><td colspan=3>drilldown data goes here...</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

another solution would be '**tbody**':

```
<tbody>
<tr><td> + </td><td>Summery row 1</td><td>Summery row 1</td></tr>
<tr><td> + </td><td>Summery row 2</td><td>Summery row 2</td></tr>
</tbody>
<tbody id=DrilldownDataOfRow2 style=hidden>
<tr><td></td><td>drilldown data goes here...</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: ah, one more thing. It needs to be valid html code. ( I don't think multiple tbody tags are allowed within one table.

Comment: Clarification: My concern is how to "connect" the summery row with the drilldown data in a logical way. (the expand/collapse of drilldown data is handled by javascript)

Comment: Multiple tbody elements are valid - they're the only markup available for grouping body rows: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.2.3

Comment: You should be looking at unordered lists <ul><li></li></ul> I think....as opposed to tables/table rows.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I actually had to do something similar for a client. As noted, you're allowed to have multiple `tbody` and `thead` tags which is what you would use to logically group your data. The `thead` in this case would be the 'connector'.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>Summary Row
  <tbody>
    <tr>Dropdown Rows / Data
  <thead>
    <tr>Summary Row
  <tbody>
    <tr>Dropdown Rows / Data
```

It's simplified but you get the idea. The structure becomes more organized and you can do much more with it with js.

I created a [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zGRSF/) with the approach I used on my project.

Comment: Nice, although a bit late :)