# Collapsing Table is applying to all tables on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hoping I can get some help with this, I'm building a page that has 5 tables on them.
2 of them are sortable using (http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)

A rather large one I want it to be collapsible, and I tried using this: 
[HTMl drilldown table: Design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154936/html-drilldown-table-design)

However, when I enable it, all the tables become collapsable, this is the jQuery from the above question.

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
   $(window).load(function(){
   $('thead').on('click', function(){
   $(this).next('tbody').toggleClass('collapsed');
 });
});
```

I'm not familiar with jQuery, so wasn't sure how to modify it so it only used the one table.  I tried using the table ID but it didn't work.

```
<?php
 $qcTable = "<table id ='thcol'>";
 foreach($tableArray as $cat=>$catData)
    {
     $title = ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$cat));
     $score = number_format($catData['sc'],2);
     $qcTable .= "<thead><tr><th>$title ($score%)</th></tr></thead><tbody class='collapsed'>";
 foreach($catData as $td=>$subCatData)
   {if($td != 'a' && $td != 'b' && $td != 'c'  && $td != 'sc'){
   $getSubCat = explode("__",$subCatData['b']);
     if(sizeof($getSubCat) ==1)
          $subTitleBuild = $getSubCat[0];
     else
          {
              unset($getSubCat[0]);
              $subTitleBuild = implode(" > ",$getSubCat);
    }
  $subtitle =  ucwords(str_replace("_"," ",$subTitleBuild));
           $subscore = number_format($subCatData['sc'],2);
     $qcTable .= "<tr><td>$subtitle ($subscore%)</td></tr>";
      }
 }            $qcTable .= "</tbody>";
      }



$qcTable .= "</table>";
echo $qcTable;
?>
```

The other two tables theads look like this:

```
  <table class = 'sortable'><thead><th class='sorttable_numeric'>
  Ticket ID</th><th>Game</th><th>Agent</th><th>Score</th><th>Star</th></thead><tbody>
```

Thank you in advance,
C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line

```
$('thead').on('click', ...);
```

put an handler for the click event on all your `<thead></thead>` tags, you should put a class on the ones you want to be able to collapse like `<thead class="collapsable"></thead>` when you write them in PHP, then your line of JavaScript will be :

```
$('thead.collapsable').on('click', ...);
```

In that way, only your `thead` tags with the class `collapsable` will be able to trigger the collapse.

Comment: Thanks!  tried it but didn't work :(.  However, at least I think I know where to start looking for a solution.